# Separate PHP file for admin and user page

Tags: php, html, authentication

I am a new PHP user, currently i am developing an online food order website for a school project. Basically there will be 2 roles, admin and normal user. I have two pages in my site, home and order food page. Both users will see the same home page, but the content in the order food page would be different for both roles.

My question is, is it necessary to create new files to take care of admin, or, can i just handle it in the same file?

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have up-voted your question as you are creating your school project and you are new in Php. No need to create separate files, you need to show products on the basis of user type. You have to check user type in login.

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create session and store value in session.

```
session_start();

//For admin
$_SESSION['type'] = 'admin';

//For user
$_SESSION['type'] = 'user';

//if admin login we will check session and display admin content
if($_SESSION['type']=='admin'){
echo 'Admin content';
}

//if user login we will check session and display user content
if($_SESSION['type']=='user'){
echo 'User content';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage you content on basis of user role

You can do it like this...

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
   return;
$roles = $current_user->roles;

if (in_array('administrator',$roles) == 1){
    //content for admin
}else{
    //content for user
}
```